# Reactive Drop Down Menu with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to reference the selected item from an `ng-repeat` and then use that value to determine if another drop down menu will appear via a `ng-show`.

I specifically want to use the value you from phase to influence whether or not the hq will show up on the page. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Here is my code:

```
        <div ng-app="erasmus">
        <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div ng-controller="erasmusController">
        <center><h2>Phase:</h2></center>
        <center><select  id="phase" name="phase">
            <option ng-repeat="x in phase track by $index">{{x}}    
        </select></center>
        </div>

        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div ng-controller="erasmusController">
        <center><h2>Side:</h2></center>
        <center><select id="side" name="side">
            <option ng-repeat="x in side">{{x}} 
        </select></center>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div ng-controller="erasmusController">

        <div ng-show="showHQ">

        <center><h2 id="hq">Is HQs OOS?:</h2></center>
        <center><select id="hq" name="hq">
            <option ng-repeat="x in hq">{{x}}   
        </select></center>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="submit">
        </div>

        </form>
        </div>
        </body>
        <script>

        var app = angular.module("erasmus",[]);


        app.controller("erasmusController",function($scope){

        $scope.phase = ["Beggining","Middle","End"];
        $scope.side = ["Japanese","Allied"];

        $scope.showHQ = false;
        $scope.hq = ["Yes","No"];



        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it may be better to use `ng-options` on your select instead of `ng-repeat`. Also, if you are planning to use the value of the select for something, you may need to give it an `ng-model`.

For example:

`<select  id="side" name="side" ng-model="sideVal" ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in side"></select>`

This example may need tweaking as you need to make sure that the value of the option is set to `true` or `false`. That may require your `$scope.side` array to be a little more involved (maybe an array of objects? i.e. `[{name: 'Japanese', value:false}, {name: 'Allied', value:true}]`?)

Once that is done, all you'd need to do is set `$scope.showHQ` equal to your newly defined `$scope.sideVal` (see `ng-model` in select example). This may be done via a `$watch` like this:

```
$scope.$watch('sideVal', function(newVal, oldVal){ if(newVal !== oldVal){ $scope.showHQ = newVal;}});
```

This essentially watches `$scope.sideVal` and when it changes (`newVal !== oldVal`) it sets `$scope.showHQ` equal to the `newVal` of `$scope.sideVal`

That should trigger the `ng-show` based on whichever value is selected.

EDIT:
Added working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rmfg4460/1/

Couple things, you only need to define your controller once per page, unless you're doing something specific each time you instantiate it.

I was typing too quickly and did make the mistake of using an equals instead of a colon, this has been corrected.

Comment: Would the array have to have 'value:' instead of value=?

Comment: Also, how do I get the value from the sideVal, it does not seem to work when I try that function.

Comment: I actually ended up using check boxes and ng-click. It made it a lot easier

Comment: Probably the best with a true/false switch. Alas, I only tried to answer your question instead of optimize. Happy coding!